# Is templated literals possible in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, literals

I would like to create a literal for a template class, is this possible in C++?

I would like to do something like this:

```
template<typename T> class A
{
    A(T x);
};

template<typename T>
A<T> operator"" _d(unsigned long long int x_double)
{
    return A<T>(2 * x_double);
}

A<int> a = 4_d;
```

I can get a literal to compile if i choose that it should always return, for example `A<short>`, but is it possible in any way to get the compiler to defer the type `T` from what the assignees type?

Comment: How should compiler infer what `T` should be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is no such thing; the only template literal is for strings. But what you want is possible through a wrapper type:

```
struct ConvertToA {
    unsigned long long int init;
    template <typename T>
    operator A<T>() { return {init}; }
};

ConvertToA operator"" _d(unsigned long long int x_double)
{
    return {2 * x_double};
}
```

Comment: Maybe `auto a = 4_d .A<int>();` as an alternative.